# how to log objects & arrays in magento2

Tags: magento2

magento2 uses monolog for logging.i'm able to log strings.but i'm not able to log objects and arrays.can you give anyone syntax for this.i'm getting following error.

Object of class 'some class' could not be converted to string.

```
$object_manager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info("some_text");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Try this: put print_r($array-or-object, true) as parameter to info.

**UPDATE**

Alternatively You can log extra data using the second param, ie (for category data)

```
$object_manager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info("category_data", array('category_data', $category->getData));
```

But the array will be converted to json which isn't the most "readable" format, so for a basic log I still using `print_r` for readability.

BTW: Json output is perfect if you use "logstash" or another parser.

**LOG 4 DUMMIES:**

> If you are trying to log an entire **Quote** Object which has a lot of
> objects inside (and many recursion too) you must either log a
> specific part or use **xdebug/zend_debug** to handle such "heavy"
> data, otherwise you'll probably exhaust the allocated memory for the request.

Comment: i have checked with category object and its not working..

Comment: This does not work as the object is too big for memory

Comment: @zedBlackbeard you can log simple objects that way, if you want to log some category data can use `print_r($category->getData(),true);`

Comment: @kevando The size of the object doesn't make the answer a bad one, you can log that way plain objects/STD or arrays without any problem, but if the object is too big you can't log it this way or any other. You just can't write a complete book in a single page, try to use your brain before your fingers. – MauroNigrele 1 hour ago