# How can I output data from an install script during upgrade?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am trying to create an install script to overwrite some bluefoot configurations. I am trying to figure out what is in the `$buttonItemBlock` variable so that I can pass that to another class. However I can not get anything to print during upgrade in the console.

```
<?php

namespace vender\module\Setup;

use Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Installer\File as InstallerFile;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File as IoFile;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Attribute\ContentBlockRepository;

/**
 * Class to install data for list builder BlueFoot block
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    protected $moduleReader;

    /**
     * @var IoFile
     */
    protected $ioFile;

    /**
     * @var InstallerFile
     */
    protected $fileInstaller;

    /**
     * @var Bluefoot content block repository manager
     */
    protected $contentBlockRepository;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     *
     * @param Reader $moduleReader
     * @param IoFile $ioFile
     * @param InstallerFile $fileInstaller
     */
    public function __construct(
        Reader $moduleReader,
        IoFile $ioFile,
        InstallerFile $fileInstaller,
        ContentBlockRepository $contentBlockRepository
    ) {
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
        $this->ioFile = $ioFile;
        $this->fileInstaller = $fileInstaller;
        $this->contentBlockRepository = $contentBlockRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $buttonItemBlock = $this->contentBlockRepository->getByIdentifier('button_item');
        var_dump($buttonItemBlock);exit;

        //Install the blocks and attributes
        //$this->installData($setup);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried echo 'test'; ?

Comment: Which type of output do you need? To console? To log file?

Comment: @Macas Yes I tried that

Comment: @Furman Anyway I can get it.

Comment: Just set psr logger interface to constructor and add any log message you need. Do you need additional guide how to inject logger to installer?

Comment: @Furman Can you show me how you would do that?

Comment: Look into my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shorter Logging to the file without logger object, in case you would need to log something fast:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/debug.log');  
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();  
$logger->addWriter($writer);  
$logger->info('MESSAGE');
```

You can try this one, maybe it will suit you needs.

Comment: Can I output var_dump this way?

Comment: You can print_r($variable, true). I'm not sure about var_dump()

Answer (score 1):

You can just log to ***system.log*** using  LoggerInterface
Furman/ConsoleOutput/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: dev
 * Date: 14.02.18
 * Time: 22:26
 */

namespace Furman\ConsoleOutput\Setup;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * @var LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

/**
 * InstallData constructor.
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 */
public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger
)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

/**
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function 
install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, 
\Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $this->logger->info('test log string');

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

}

run at the root of your project

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

And see at the log file:

[image: var/log/system.log]

P.S. Don't forget to enable "*Log to File*" system/config settings at the admin panel
***Stores->Settings->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug->Log to file***

P.P.S.
Output using `echo` also works fine:
[image]

Comment: I am starting to wonder if my install script is being called. I should be able to just disable the module and re-enable it -> run magento upgrade and it should work right?

Comment: No, you just need to kill your module row in setup_module table at the DB

Comment: Yup just did that :). Looks like its working now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: One more thing, what is the $context param on that function?

Comment: This object allows you to get your module version from Gene\BlueFoot\etc\module.xml. Nothing special, It's more useful in UpgradeScripts,  when you need to run something if the version of module lower then...

Comment: The problem with this log functionality though is, I can not output a var_dump to it. I need to be able to do that. Not just a string.

Comment: You don't need to var_dump anything to logger parameter. Just pass this to logger. No matter string is this or array or object - it will be logged, But keep in mind, that in Magento every class has plenty of dependencies, so If you'll log one object - > you'll log all inner objects that were injected to it. So it can take a lot of time and allow big performance. So I don't recommend to log objects, rather log it's properties or better way - use XDebug, this is very powerful tool!

Comment: My fault, this was in first magento, I'ts not allowed in second. Try to use "print_r" function for arrays.

Comment: This is also good answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76381/46822